# autovacuum challenges after upgrade to postgresql 9.6

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, vacuum, autovacuum, performance-tuning

We have a cluster with several dozen databases.  It was running great on 9.3 for a year (growing over time) when we did the upgrade to 9.6 last month.  Since that time, the database will freeze on updates of large tables (tables with 100k+ rows), from between a minute, to 30-60 minutes.

Specifically, one of our processes updates several columns one-at-a-time in such a table, and in the code log, I can see where it pauses and hangs, for up to 30 minutes, and then picks up later as if nothing happened, and updates many consecutive columns in the same with no such hang, within seconds.

Increasing logging in the database showed nothing at first - and analysis of memory usage on the server and in postgres showed nothing unusual for resource usage.  Eventually, I was able to see, with debug-level logging, that postgresql would go through vacuuming all databases, and the query in question would un-stick after the autovacuumer would hit that database, though not on the first loop of all databases, but after several passes.  Since then, I have been messing with the autovacuum settings.  I tried turning autovacuuming off, as it was off on 9.3 and somehow we survived - but that did not help.  So I turned it on, and have been changing various settings as I learn about them.  I got it so that the production server does not hang in this way through frequent autovacuuming, adding 16 workers, etc.

I am pasting the settings I have in general for our db server - the general memory settings were created with pgtune, the autovacuum settings I have been essentially tinkering with.

I am learning but am very much shooting in the dark - if anyone can provide guidance on how best to handle the analysis (through logs, etc) and optimizing of the autovacuuming on this instance of 9.6, that is what I am after.

Various queries at the official site and here designed to show locks don't turn up any waiting processes at all - but I do see at least one each entry for a process with an 'AccessShareLock' and 'RowExclusiveLock' in the pg admin iv dashboard, under Locks, when the query to update the column is running.

Again, what is frustrating - I don't see what is so complicated about a column update of a few hundred thousand records, one-at-a-time - it should be easy to see what is causing the hang (something about autovacuuming), and also how to fix it.  Whereas the settings below seem to be working on production, I am not clear on the why, don't know how to improve them, and don't know how to create a working set of configurations on a dev server.  Your help is appreciated.

```
autovacuum = on       
log_autovacuum_min_duration = 200            
autovacuum_max_workers = 16      
autovacuum_naptime = 1min               
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 5000     

#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 500   
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000                                          
#autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age = 

autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms     
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = 2000    
default_statistics_target = 100
maintenance_work_mem = 2920MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.8
effective_cache_size = 22GB
work_mem = 260MB
wal_buffers = 16MB
shared_buffers = 7680MB
min_wal_size = 80MB
max_wal_size = 2GB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you change your strategy.

> Specifically, one of our processes updates several columns **one-at-a-time** in such a table, and in the code log, I can see where it pauses and hangs, for up to 30 minutes, and then picks up later as if nothing happened, and updates many consecutive columns in the same with no such hang, within seconds.

One such update can easily *double* the size of your table, since each `UPDATE` is basically equivalent to one `DELETE` one `INSERT`, which leaves each *deleted* row occupying useless space until the table it is `VACUUM`ed and that space can be reused for the next round of `UPDATE`s.

You can do:

1. Change the strategy and update as many columns as you can at once. Your process will be much quicker because the data will be accessed many less times.
2. Issue a `VACUUM` from your code after each `UPDATE` round, so that the unused spaced is available for the next `UPDATE` round.
3. Under some circumstances, doing the `UPDATE`s in batches of (let's say) 1.000, and committing after each batch might ease the sitution.

Any combination of the three techniques will probably ease the updates.

Comment: In the rather complicated context which of course cannot be provided here in detail, the method of one column update at a time is best, I assure you - and will be in place for this version of the code.  The updates work fine - great in fact - once 'unstuck' - they just get stuck sometimes, at a 'random' column, and I know for a fact it is not a particular column or data type that causes it.  So, while your feedback is insightful, and I am sure you are right, I am going to wait for an answer that helps me determine why the updates are sticking.

Comment: Try option 2 if you can. It's the easier to implement, and *might* make a substantial difference.

Comment: cant edit comment above - I missed your suggestion #2, and I am going to try that first, and will mark you correct if it works

Comment: doesnt fix it - verbose vacuum of the destination table says this, where the line with nonremovable rows is constantly updating if I re-run -    INFO:  vacuuming "public.xyz"
INFO:  index "xyz_seq1" now contains 565893 row versions in 2897 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages have been deleted, 0 are currently reusable.
CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.00 sec.
INFO:  "xyz": found 0 removable, 64447 nonremovable row versions in 923 out of 38054 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be re
There were 503 unused item pointers.
Skipped 1 page due to buffer pins.

Comment: Do you have any open transactions while all this is happening? Either your own transaction is still locking some row, or you (probably) have some kind of concurrency problem.

Comment: Your suggestion #2 did, manually vacuuming the tables, does work, and doesn't require further changes.  I manually vacuum the source table once, and the destination between each column update - not sure which one fixed it, or if both did.  Awesome, thanks.